# Get value of input field from other websites html code

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the value of a hidden input field from twitters follow page. I'm using file_get_contents on the url and then try to get the value of the input with the preg_match_all function but something in my code isn't working because I just get back an empty array. I would really appreciate it if someone would look over my code and help me get it to work.

HTML Code of the input field I want to get the value from (in this example **twitter**)

```
<input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="twitter">
```

My code snippet I don't get to work

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"screen_name\" value=\"(.*?)\">/", $html, $screen_name);
echo "<pre>", print_r($screen_name, true), "</pre>";
```

This code should output the value of the input field in this example just **twitter** within an array.

**Edit:** My code snippet works find I just haven't noticed that Twitter only shows this hidden input field if your logged in on twitter and of course if you use file_get_contents your webserver will not be logged in to twitter and can't get the HTML code what you get if you are logged in. Thanks to [vigikaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5664657/vigikaran) for pointing this out to me and to [gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693294/gilbert) for improving the regex in my code snippet.

Comment: does the variable `$html` contain any data after using `file_get_contents`?

Comment: did you check the file_get_content result first ?

Comment: Yes I check and it contains the source code but after using preg_match_all all I get is an empty array with 2 other empty arrays inside.

Comment: Do you know you can test your regex with tools like http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: I tried it on my server and it worked well. The regex seems fine.

Comment: IMO you would find it much simpler to use `DOMDocument` I think rather than a regex

Comment: I think you can use it - [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) . with it you can get data easier

Comment: @Max can you try it with this link please? https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=783214

Comment: there is no <input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="twitter">
in the link you provided

Comment: @Vigikaranomg thank for for pointing this out to me this input field is only showing if you are logged in. I'm so stupid thank you xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [vigikaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5664657/vigikaran) for pointing this out to me my code is fine and works but the HTML code I got from twitter doesn't contain the hidden input field I was looking for because It only shows this input field if your logged in and of course if you use file_get_contents your webserver will not be logged in. Thanks to everyone for the help and to [gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693294/gilbert) for improving the regex from my code snippet.

Comment: You are welcome. Screen scraping is always a risky business as pages change so often.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="twitter">';
    preg_match_all('/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"screen_name\" value=\"(.*?)\">/', $html, $screen_name);
    echo "<pre>", print_r($screen_name, true), "</pre>";
```

You can check it here https://eval.in/626194

The string is in `$screen_name[1][0]`

Comment: Also works for me I just have not noticed you have to be logged in to twitter to get this hidden input field and your webserver that get the code with file_get_content will not be logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually grabbing a Twitter page I notice your regular expression is susceptible to extra white space within html tags. This can be a real problem for screen scraping.  Try:

```
'/<input\s+type="hidden"\s+name="screen_name"\s+value="(.*?)">/',
```

or if you want to have a better ability to resist small changes on Twitter's part the following will work as long as name= precedes value=:

```
 '/<input\s+[^<>]*\s+name\s*=\s*"screen_name"[^<>]*\s+value\s*=\s*"(.*?)">/',
```

(edited above to improve resistance to white-space changes)